# GAE syncing content between the server and the local development machine

Tags: google-app-engine, synchronization

Lets say on my local machine in the folder which contains my GAE project I have an images folder.

When I upload the app to the GAE with the correct .yaml information the images folder and its contents will be uploaded.

Now lets say, I'm running the APP online and I upload an image to the image folder now on Google's servers. Now the images folders contents on the web and on my local development machine are different.

My question is this:

Next time I upload the app to GAE, how will the discrepancy between the different contents of the image folder be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add files to the application like that after deployment. The local file system is read-only to GAE applications.

If you were to upload an image (via a handler you create) when the app is deployed you can't save it in the image folder in your application, you can only save it to the data/blob store. The files you uploaded with your app are static, they cannot be changed either by you or the application outside of the deployment tool. You can read them in, sure, but not write to them once deployed/at all.

So the situation will never arise that a deployed version has different files to the local version - they are always identical.

Comment: Thank you for your well written answer.