# GAE datastore sync

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment, synchronization

This question really follows on from this question:

[GAE syncing content between the server and the local development machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14628438/gae-syncing-content-between-the-server-and-the-local-development-machine)

If an item is added to the Datastore on the local development machine, will this item then be added to the apps online Datastore?

Or is all data added locally erased before deployment and the data on the online Datastore unchanged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your local data is independent of the datastore, there is no syncing of data. The services like datastore, blobstore and so on are emulated locally by stubs.